# ObjectInputStream readObject() erratic behavior?

Tags: android, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I am currently making an app for our group in high school. We decided to make a personal financing app that organizes your spendings.
I am trying to use internal storage for storing data. I have created an `InternalStorage` class just for that (it was someone else's answer to a question like mine but I forgot from where. Whoops.), having `write` and `read` methods accordingly. 
However, while debugging I found some implausible behavior.

```
public final class InternalStorage {
    private static String key = "billify";

    public static void write(Context context, List<Bill> billList){
        try{
             FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(billList);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Internal storage write error: IOException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public static List<Bill> read(Context context){
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            List<Bill> a = (List<Bill>) ois.readObject();//jumps from here
            return a;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context,"Internal storage read error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;//jumps to here w/o triggering previous two lines.
        }
    }
}
```

I have put breakpoints in all the lines of code from `read()`, and from what I saw, the code ran `ois.readObject()`, then **without running e.printStackTrace() and Toast, jumped straight back to `return null`.**

Does anybody know what's going on?

Edit:

```
    if(z.getClass() == cls){
        ArrayList<Bill> a = (ArrayList<Bill>) z;//Jumps from here now
        return a;
    }
    return null;
```

Doing a checked cast still makes the same thing happen-the classes are same, but doing the cast still makes it jump to the previous, last `null`.

Comment: What actually gets returned? Smells like it's just the way debugger displays things, trying to translate between bytecode and source code. End-of-method in your bytecode to the debugger looks like it corresponds to the last `return null` in your code.

Comment: Now that you said and I checked, it actually returned a list with 3 elements in it! The plot thickens...

Comment: So...it correctly returns the `ArrayList<Bill>`, but why does it trigger the `catch` block & jump to `return null`?

Comment: It doesn't. It just a a side effect of the debugger working on bytecode level and not always being able to exactly map back to your source code.

Comment: So it actually works correctly, but the debugger thinks otherwise? Thanks a lot, BTW.

Comment: note that when you are debugging and use the expression window you might break streams behavior - once a stream read is performed, it will never be performed again. If you evaluate it once, when you continue, you will get nothing.